# React app looking for bundle.js in component folder not project root

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

The errors I get below are shown in the console after I refresh on a nested route (register/email-confirmation). Whereas non-nested routes do not get this error.

I think the main problem is that it's searching for bundle.js and the image *in* the nested route path, as opposed to the root path.

**The errors in my console:**

`GET http://localhost:3002/register/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

`Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3002/register/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

`GET http://localhost:3002/register/a5e694be93a1c3d22b85658bdc30008b.png 404 (Not Found)`

**My webpack.config.js:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "./client/build" );
const SOURCE_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, "./client/src" );
const PUBLIC_PATH = "/";

...

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  context: SOURCE_PATH,

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', SOURCE_PATH + '/index.jsx'],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /server/],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-1', 'stage-0', 'stage-2'],
            plugins: [
              'transform-decorators-legacy',
              'transform-es2015-destructuring',
              'transform-es2015-parameters',
              'transform-object-rest-spread'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },

  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    port: 3002,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: BUILD_PATH,
    publicPath: PUBLIC_PATH,
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(appConstants),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/index.html'),
      inject: true
    }),
  ],

  watch: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about this bug, but I highly recommend using [fuse-box](https://fuse-box.org/)

[fuse-box](https://fuse-box.org/) is the future of the build systems, within few minutes you will be running your project with high speed hot reload and many others utitilites...

check this [react example seed](https://github.com/fuse-box/react-example), it's incredibly amazing..

Comment: Can definitely back this answer. Ported our project over from Webpack to FuseBox recently and not looking back. Our project is quite complex and our build process uses a few node environment variables that require dynamic imports and so on, so was a bit tricky to get it working but the benefits far outweigh the time it to get it working. But to get my playground app converted and working so I could test FuseBox features in it took maybe 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `base` option in HTMLWebPackPlugin.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
            title: 'my title',
            static: 'static',
            base: '/',
        }),
```

It's append tag base in header. Then works fine.

```
<base href='/'>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options